R8: Hilt injection using @Qualifiers fails with DuplicateBinding after upgrade to AGP 8.4
After upgrading to AGP 8.4 I've faced a lot of build issues for the release build, mainly to do with R8 library keep rules.
But now I've stumbled upon another issue:
MyApplication_HiltComponents.java:382: error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher is bound multiple times:
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements MyApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
          @Provides @Singleton kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher com.myapp.repo.DispatcherModule.providesDefaultDispatcher()
          @Provides @Singleton kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher com.myapp.repo.DispatcherModule.providesIoDispatcher()
          @Provides @Singleton kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineDispatcher com.myapp.repo.DispatcherModule.providesMainDispatcher()

The Hilt module and annotations:
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DispatcherModule {

    @DefaultDispatcher
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesDefaultDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default

    @IoDispatcher
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesIoDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO

    @MainDispatcher
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun providesMainDispatcher(): CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main
}
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class IoDispatcher

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class DefaultDispatcher

@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class MainDispatcher

the rules I added for the module and anotations:

-keep public class com.myapp.** { public *; }
-keep, allowobfuscation public class com.myapp.**ModuleKt
-keep, allowobfuscation public class com.myapp.**EntryPointKt

-keepnames class * extends android.os.Parcelable
-keepnames class * extends java.io.Serializable

-keep class com.myapp.repo.DispatcherModule*

I am pretty sure it's still related to R8 somehow. The debug build works fine
I tried:

upgrading hilt to 1.2.0,
adding android.disableMinifyLocalDependenciesForLibraries=true to gradle.properties
adding class specific keep rules, general keep rules, @Keep anotations on each class and @Provide method


If possible can you report this on the R8 issue tracker, https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=326788&template=1025938? And do if you have reproduction you can share that would of course be great.

did you tried removing @Singleton annotations from every function in DispatcherModule ?
